# Is it possible to play Battlefield 4 multiplayer maps without playing online?

Tags: battlefield-4

I'm not that kind of professional in First Person Shooter games, so I seldom play online. I've seen on internet before that a super big skyscraper in Siege of Shanghai map, and I'd like to try destroying it so are there methods to load the map with only me inside?

Comment: *I'm not that kind of professional in First Person Shooter games, so I seldom play online* is the worst excuse I ever heard. Just play with real players, you will learn a lot in a very short period of time

Comment: Whatever you think if this "excuse" is the worst or not, I'm sticking to single player. I like those games with stories.

Answer (score 2):

No. The only way to do this is to join an empty server. You can go to Battlelog, filter by "Siege of Shanghai" map and "all" free slots. If you're not that good, you could always find a "newbie only" or "training server" for practise.